# The application can not find a path to a file after build project using setuptools

Tags: python, python-3.x, build, filepath, setuptools

I am trying to build a project using setuptools. In my project appears essential `config.yaml` file. I've appointed this like that:

```py
setup=(
# some stuff
    include_package_data=True,
    package_data={
        "": ["*.yaml"]
    },
# some remains stuff
)
```

but I obtain the issue when `config.yaml` isn't found. It occurs when I am starting an app.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\github\\Cats_Queue_Management_System\\env\\lib\\site-packages\\kitty_getter-1.0-py3.8.egg\\application\\config.yaml'
```

However, it's been copied. (As I properly understood).

```
copying build\lib\application\config.yaml -> build\bdist.win32\egg\application
```

The file-interaction within python code:

```py
# some stuff
default_file = Path(__file__).parent.parent / 'config.yaml'
    with open(default_file, 'r') as f:
        config = yaml.safe_load(f)
# some remains stuff
```

The arrangement of the project looks like follow:

```
Project/
 +- app/
 |    +- __init__.py
 |    +- src/
 |    |   +- __init__.py
 |    |   +- config_processing.py
 |    +- entry_point.py
 |    +- config.yaml
 +- setup.py
```

Or more fully version (the file-interaction befall at `settings.py`):

[image]

Also, I'd like to note that if I launch the app directly, I mean `python entry_point.py`, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Because the file do not exist there... Your .yaml file is on **D:\github\Cats_Queue_Management_System\application\config.yaml** you try it to search it on the wrong path

Try this to see:

```py
import os

fileName = "config.yaml"
appPath = r"D:\github"

for r,d,f in os.walk(appPath):
    for file in f:
        if file == fileName:
            print(os.path.abspath(file))
        else:
            print(f"File {fileName} is not exist!")
```

This will search your file on all appPath folders and subfolders and if is found will print the absolute path of that file, if not will tell you that file is not exist.